# My jquery image slider autoplay is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a jquery image slider that works fine when I click previous and next. However, when I click play, the first image fades and then the second image normally appears. Then it fades back to the first and second image again before going to the third and it just goes on and on.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


    <script src="jqslideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="nature.jpg" id="slideshow" name="slideshows" width="500" height="300">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><a href="javascript:changeImage(-1)">Previous</a></td>
            <td align="right"><a href="javascript:changeImage(1)">Next</a></td>
            <td id="play_stop" align="right"><a href="javascript:play()">Play</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>

<!-----------------------------------These are separate files---------------------------------------->

var Image = new Array("nature.jpg","treehouse.jpg","drstrange.jpg");

var ImageNumber = 0;

var ImageLength = Image.length - 1;

var Interval;

function changeImage(num){
ImageNumber = ImageNumber + num;

if(ImageNumber > ImageLength){
    ImageNumber = 0;
}

else if(ImageNumber < 0){
    ImageNumber = ImageLength;
}

$(document).ready(function(){


$('#slideshow').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(this).attr('src', src());
        }).fadeIn('slow');  

});

function src(){
document.slideshows.src = Image[ImageNumber];
}

}

function play(){
Interval = setInterval("changeImage(1)", 1000);
document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = "<a       
href='javascript:stop()'>Stop</a>";
}

function stop(){
document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = "<a  
href='javascript:play()'>Play</a>";
clearInterval(Interval);
}
```

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle with external resources

Comment: Hi, I'm not really familiar with this JSFiddle, I don't even know how to run my jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/renboy94/7Cbw6/7/